# Timer before executing action again

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

In a switch statement I have a case, which represents a logout button in a game. The problem is if a player repetitively clicks it over and over it executes the c.logout() method again and again causing huge amounts of lag in my game. I'm wanting to add a timer before the player can click the button again. I'm pretty new to threads and timers so I'd really appreciate some help on this. Especially if you could explain it. Thanks a lot.

This is my code

```
    case 9154: // Logout Button
        c.logout();
        break;
```

Solution thanks to Ryan

Just making a simpile boolean to keep track of the log in state.

```
case 9154: // Logout Button
    if (loggedIn) {
        loggedIn = false;
        c.logout();
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Please improve your question by telling more of the pertinent details. Please help us gain an understanding of what could possibly be going wrong.

Comment: Nothing really much more to say. If a player spam clicks the log out button it lags the whole game. I need a timer before allowing them to click it again if they've already clicked it once. HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: How about disabling the button after it is clicked?

Comment: For one, what GUI library are you using? Come on now, we can't read minds. And why would pushing a button cause lag? What logic is being inveighed there?

Comment: I'm guessing that you forgot to use the [tag:android] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a variable of their status:

```
case 9154: // Logout Button
    if (loggedIn) {
        loggedIn = false;
        c.logout();
    }
    break;
```

Then set loggedIn back to true when they log in.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try this out of all the stuff I tried. Haha thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

may you do not have to start a new thread, just use a lock to prevent calling logout twice.

One of the first google results as an example:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html